# Flex 4: Popup Anchor : Right to Left Display of Drop down

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I customized flex 4 combobox to display popup in an auto width layout. But combobox shows dropdown list from Left to right as you can see in the Left side of image.

I actually want to display dropdown starting from right side, as described in the highlighted image.

Thanks

[image]
<sub>(source: [adobe.com](https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-2848524-29191/450-153/popupanchor.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could override the calculatePopUpPosition method to adjust the y position together with RIGHT for the popup position. Or maybe experiment with constraint based layout setting right - 0?

Its stupid that there is no BOTTOM_RIGHT property for spark.components.PopUpPosition

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/PopUpPosition.html

Comment: I tried setting right = 0 but vain. as for calculation, i'm pretty confused at this point, not good at math